# Tree model structure with Immutable.js's Record & Redux & Typescript

Tags: typescript, redux, immutable.js

I receive a flat structure from my API:

```
{
    "users": [
         {"id": 123, "name": "Peter"},
         {"id": 124, "name": "John"}
    ],
    "threads": [
         {"id": 1, "participantIds": [123, 124, 125]},
         {"id": 2, "participantIds": [879, 888]}
    ]
}
```

where `participantIds` refers to user "entities".

I would like to store the data in Redux's was, i.e an immutable flat structure. For convience, I've created Record entities, which I would like to receive as an input (props) in my React components:

```
export class User extends Immutable.Record({})
{
    id: string;
    name: string;
}

export class Thread extends Immutable.Record({})
{
    id: string;
    paticipants: Immutable.Map<string, User>;
}
```

Since Redux's flat structure is different, I'm not sure, how exactly build this architecture properly. Here is a little summary what I might have done:

1. Use Reselect library and transform the flat state to tree state.

   1. Store data as raw Immutable.js Map & List and then in selector converts them into the entities.
   2. Introduce property Thread->participantIds and fill the Thread->participants in reselect, so the property before running the selector is empty.
   3. Create a layer in between, something like MVVM, so I would have two type of entities, one for storing the data, other for passing to the React components.
2. Store the tree state and do updates on all possible occurences of particular (User) entity.

I do not like neither of these possible solutions. All of them seem to be pretty verbose for such usual and simple usecase.

---

I found a little discussion here: https://github.com/rackt/redux/issues/815 But I didn't get the anwers I need.

Comment: Your API data is normalized as it should be and it __is__ the state of your application. You simply _have to_ map the participant ID to the respective user entity if you want the data to be useful. You seem to be reaching for a different answer than the one concluded in the discussion you linked, but I do not think you will find a better one. As Dan Abramov said, "[That's the tradeoff](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25701168/at-what-nesting-level-should-components-read-entities-from-stores-in-flux/25701169#25701169)."